# Duplicate Class Found (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting an error message I don't know how to fix:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Here is my Gradle file:

```
 dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha11'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'


}
```

[image]

I have tried adding this line to build.gradle(app):

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

and I tried adding `android.enableJetifier=true` in gradle.properties. I saw similar issues but all the answers I tried nothing worked for me.

Comment: try upgrading the version of kotlin

Comment: The issue is that I'm using Java, I don't know why the error mentions Kotlin + I don't know how to upgrade it

Comment: attach bulld.gradle (app) file also in the question

Comment: I did add it you can see it now

Comment: as you have not included the whole file, do you have added these  in you build file 

APP LEVEL -- 

1. plugin id -- 'kotlin-android'

dependecies -- 

    // Java language implementation
2.    implementation "androidx.core:core:$core_version"
    
    // Kotlin
3.    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    
4.    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"


PROJECT LEVEL ---

 5.      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
6.  check if there is mavenCentral() added in repository or not

Comment: clean , rebuild and check

Comment: @Okashi Downgrade `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.6.0'` to older version `2.5.3` as here added `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.5.3'`. And let me know solved or not.